# display text without HTML markup

Tags: html, jsp, text, rendering

I was just going through the following URL, and i noticed that when i click on view source there is no HTML markup.I want to do something similar.
http://data-gov.tw.rpi.edu/demo/linked/demo-401-budget-summary-sparql.php?agency=National%2BScience%2BFoundataion

I have a database with some queries, I want a user to be able to access the queries in a similar fashion as above.
I know how to use the request.getParameter function in JSP to retrieve the value of querystring , which i will then use to fetch corresponding query from database, but i am not sure how to display it without html markup

Comment: It's just a text document. It was sent with the HTTP header `Content-type: text/plain`, and "styled" with new-lines and tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a jsp page without any html markup. Just print query.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set the `Content-Type` to `text/plain; charset=UTF-8`. That way it'll retain the line breaks.

Comment: wouldn't that force the user to download it as .txt file?

Comment: @Priyam Nope. The link you provided actually has `Content-Type` set to `text/plain; charset=UTF-8`